# Woocommerce add_to_cart without variation id

Tags: woocommerce

I have this code:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
```

And If I try to on product which has variation, this still works and the product is added to the cart (although I havent provided other parameters for variation). Is this intended behavior, is there an error handler in case it fails?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting case. This will pass only if the request is through ajax.
It should fail if its through the regular HTTP request due to the additional check in `add_to_cart_handler_variable()` function

if It's an ajax request, The variable product will be added and the product will take the lowest price ( the lowest regular/sale price from all variations ).

you should avoid doing that. you should pass the variation id too.

Comment: Yes, it is through ajax. I havent mentioned that.